# Git track a remote branch and push to a different branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I am having a local feature branch say `f_branch1` which tracks a remote branch `develop`. At the end of my day, I pushed my local branch to remote which create a new remote branch `f_branch1`.
Next day I updated my local branch from remote `develop` branch to make sure I have the latest code. Now, end of this day, when I try to push my changes to the remote branch which was created the previous day, I get this error

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'remote url.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This makes sense, but then how can I avoid this error?

**EDIT**

I mean, because I updated my local branch with develop, so the tip of my local `f_branch1`is ahead of its remote `f_branch1`, that's why I get this error. All I want is to keep my work safe on remote in a feature branch but at the same time, keep my working code updated from a common branch `develop`.

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense? Looks like you've broke the local branch, look at the commit tree closely.

Comment: The error message caused by your local `f_branch1` is behind. And can you add the branch structure by showing the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`? BTW, if you need to work on two different branches separately, you'd better use two local branches to track `origin/f_branch1` and `origin/develop` separately.

Comment: Have you solve the problem yet?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Well, all I am doing now is keep tracking my local feature branch with one remote branch and periodically merging the remote feature branch with the local branch so that I can push back my local feature branch to this remote feature branch. Hope I was able to explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you update your branch f_branch1 with develop ? For this case you should rebase your branch f_branch1

```
 git checkout f_branch1
 git rebase develop
```